# How do you trigger a build in Azure Pipelines when a new tag is pushed to github.com?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I [asked this on twitter](https://twitter.com/dstaheli/status/1043635525918380033) a couple of weeks ago and then spent a few weekend hours [on this issue](https://github.com/ctaggart/SourceLink/issues/373) trying to figure it out. I want to trigger a build when a new tag is pushed to github.com. Most other CI services have this capability, but I can't figure out how to enable it for Azure Pipelines. I tried adding a `trigger` of `refs/tags/*` in the `azure-pipelines.yaml` and in the UI where you can override the triggers. Neither has worked for me.

Comment: Not sure whether this helps but someone told me that you need to make sure not to override the triggers in the web UI. Having said that, I have the right settings in the UI and it doesn't work either.

Comment: using refs/tags/* will trigger if you are configured to auth from Azure Pipelines to Github using Oauth, however, that is currently broken when using the GitHub App based auth.  The team is working on a fix.

Answer (score 5):

I feel like even though this should be the default, I needed set the triggers to `*` to get tags (and branches) to build

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include: ['*']
  tags:
    include: ['*']
```

Comment: According to this document, it is supposed to be the default: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#tags  > "If you don't specify any tag triggers, the default is as if you wrote:"trigger: tags: include: -*"

Comment: Hence why I mention that it should be the default. There is a discrepancy between what the documentation states and what is practiced. (The yaml example listed is even invalid yaml). I'm sure the azure pipelines team will fix this soon, but it is what's needed right now.

Comment: Thanks so much for this. Have been struggling with this all day.

Comment: No idea why this is not working for me in Azure dev ops yaml file